# How to change text alignment and direction in Word document using VBA macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I was searching for paragraph text direction changing using macro for Word doc and I got nothing.

I just found solution for Excel cells:
http://software-solutions-online.com/excel-vba-reading-order/

Comment: Have you tried to record a macro in Word to see how Word does it?

Comment: FWIW - I was feeling bored, so just spent about a minute and googled for solutions to this within stackoverflow.com.  Although I didn't find one single page that answered both of your questions, I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8729424/6535336) which shows how to change alignment, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6330330/6535336) which shows how to change direction.  (I ignored the search results pointing to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/paragraphformat-object-word) that I found by googling the question title, as that seemed too easy.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set obj = objWord.Documents.Open("path\to\file")

Dim par
Dim myParas
Set myParas = obj.Paragraphs

For i = 1 To myParas.Count '''Iterate over all paragraphs
Set par =myParas(i)
par.ReadingOrder = xlRTwdReadingOrderRtl '''set text direction(aka Reading Order)
par.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 3
Next

obj.save
obj.close
```

Also you can run it from cmd with cscript.exe